# What is the limit on creating classifiers for one instance of Visual recognition service

Tags: visual-recognition

I would like to know how many maximum classifiers can be created for given instance of standard plan of IBM visual recognition service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can create maximum 100 classifiers for given instance of standard plan of IBM visual recognition service.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a hard limit on the number of classifiers you can create.  If you create many (like dozens) and try to use them all in a single /classify request at the same time, you may experience higher latency, though. However, you can work around this by sending requests in parallel to use a number of classifiers which gives an acceptable amount of latency.

Comment: Thanks Matt. surprisingly I don't find any info in IBM documentation. Had checked with customer support but they dint revert back.

Comment: thanks for your comments... I think you're right and this info is missing from the official docs